# Berkeley DB equivalent of SELECT COUNT(*) All, SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE LIKE "%...%"

Tags: sql, berkeley-db

I'm looking for Berkeley DB equivalent of

```
SELECT COUNT All, SELECT COUNT WHERE LIKE "%...%"
```

I have got 100 records with keys: 1, 2, 3, ... 100.

I have got the following code:

```
//Key = 1
i=1;
strcpy_s(buf, to_string(i).size()+1, to_string(i).c_str());
key.data = buf;
key.size = to_string(i).size()+1;
key.flags = 0;
data.data = rbuf;
data.size = sizeof(rbuf)+1;
data.flags = 0;

//Cursor
if ((ret = dbp->cursor(dbp, NULL, &dbcp, 0)) != 0) {
    dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->cursor");
    goto err1;
}

//Get
dbcp->get(dbcp, &key, &data_read, DB_SET_RANGE);
db_recno_t cnt;

dbcp->count(dbcp, &cnt, 0);
cout <<"count: "<<cnt<<endl;
```

Count cnt is always 1 but I expect it calculates all the partial key matches for Key=1: 1, 10, 11, 21, ... 91. 
What is wrong in my code/understanding of DB_SET_RANGE ? 
Is it possible to get SELECT COUNT WHERE LIKE "%...%" in BDB ? 
Also is it possible to get SELECT COUNT All records from the file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting Berkeley DB to be way more high-level than it actually is. It doesn't contain anything like what you're asking for. If you want the equivalent of `WHERE field LIKE '%1%'` you have to make a cursor, read through *all* the values in the DB, and do the string comparison yourself to pick out the ones that match. That's what an SQL engine actually does to implement your query, and if you're using libdb instead of an SQL engine, it's up to you. If you want it done faster, you can use a secondary index (much like you can create additional indexes for a table in SQL), but you have to provide some code that links the secondary index to the main DB.

`DB_SET_RANGE` is useful to optimize a very specific case: you're looking for items whose key *starts with* a specific substring. You can `DB_SET_RANGE` to find the first matching key, then `DB_NEXT` your way through the matches, and stop when you get a key that doesn't match. This works only on `DB_BTREE` databases because it depends on the keys being returned in lexical order.

The count method tells you how many *exact duplicate* keys there are for the item at the current cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method [**DB->stat()**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/api_reference/C/dbstat.html).

For example, number of unique keys in the BT_TREE.

```
bool row_amount(DB *db, size_t &amount) {
    amount = 0;
    if (db==NULL) return false;
    DB_BTREE_STAT *sp;
    int ret =  db->stat(db, NULL, &sp, 0);
    if(ret!=0) return false;
    amount = (size_t)sp->bt_nkeys;
    return true; 
}
```